# How to validate data insertions and restrict them in Excel cells

Tags: regex, excel

I have an Asp.Net web application to manage certain tables in the database. I'm using Grid to insert, update the Database. In addition to this, the requirement is that, user should be able to insert into database from Excel(by uploading the Excel, sort of like Import from Excel into Database).
So, I'm reusing the code for insertions(which i used for Insert in Grid) for each row in the Excel.

And I have Regular expression validators for certain fieldsin Grid in Asp.Net as follows:

Id: can be combination of numbers,alphabets. Regex is:`"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,50}$"`

Formula: can have arithmetic operators and dot. Regex is: `"^[ A-Za-z0-9%._(/*+)-]*$"`

Sort Order:  must be nuber with some max size Regex is: `"^[0-9]{1,5}$"`

Weight: real number with max size Regex is : `"^[0-9]+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$"`

Domain UserName: username with domain name Regex is: `"^[a-zA-Z\\._]{1,200}$"`

I wanted to have this validators in the Excel cells too. I've searched if Excel allows Regular expressions and found that it should be done through vba or any third party tool. I don't know Vb.net and neither want to use any external tool.

And i don't know much about Excel too. Is there any way to do the validations. If so, will there be some formats for setting formula for regex.

Can anyone suggest me how to do this. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/apply-data-validation-to-cells-HP010072600.aspx

Comment: @Axel - Thanks, but I want help withe the macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Regex engine that comes with VBScript:

```
Dim User_ID As String
User_ID = InputBox("Enter User ID:")

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
     .Global = True
     .Pattern = "^[\w]{1,50}$"
     If .Test(User_ID) Then '// Check pattern matches User_ID string
        Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = User_ID
     Else
        MsgBox("Invalid ID, please try again!")
     End If
End With
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. But can you please tell how to call this block of code from Excel . Should i write this in a function and call it from any cell?

Comment: You can literally copy and paste this into a code module in the workbook (Press Alt + F11 to access the VBA-IDE window) If you want  it to automatically be triggered when the user chages a cell then I  would look at using the Worksheet_Change() event within the workbook.

Comment: Hi, I've used that code in functions and bound them to the cells. They are working fine. I'm allowing users to download that Excel format when they click on Import option in Asp Page, so that, they can fill and upload the file. When user opens the downloaded file, the functions are executed and throwing pop-up that "Field must not be empty" for each cell to which they are bound. Is there a way to execute those functions only when that particular cell is changed?

Comment: You would have to turn Calculation mode off and have the cells only calculate when they're changed using the Worksheet_Change event. It's a bit messy though if you don't know what you're doing with events or error trapping in Excel so I'd recommend trying to change the design of the workbook before taking that approach.

Comment: If i use Worksheet_Change and call those functions from that, then whatever cell is modified, all the calls will be executed .. right? Example: I have ProjectId and ProjectName cells with validations in my sheet, if i modify ProjectId, then both ProjectId and ProjectName will be validated. Or is there a way to have different Change events for different cells?

Comment: I got that. Thank you for your responses. I've included if else block in Worksheet_change event. I'll post the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I've wrote worksheet_Change event with if else

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub '// Only look at header row

Application.EnableEvents = False '// Disable events, prevent infinite loop.
If Cells(1, Target.Column).Value = "Attribute_Id" Then
    Target.Value = AttributeId(Target.Value)
ElseIf Cells(1, Target.Column).Value = "Attribute_Name" Then
    Target.Value = AttributeName(Target.Value)
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True '// Turn Events back on

End Sub
```

And these are the functions:

```
Function AttributeId(Attribute_Id As String) As String

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
   .Global = True
   .Pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,50}$"
   .IgnoreCase = True

If Not .Test(Attribute_Id) Then
    MsgBox ("Invalid Attribute ID, please try again!")
    Exit Function
End If

End With

AttributeId = Attribute_Id

End Function
```

And

```
Function AttributeName(Attribute_Name As String) As String

If Attribute_Name = "" Then MsgBox ("Attribute Name is a Mandatory field!")
AttributeName = Attribute_Name

End Function
```

No need to bind the functions to the cells.

-- Thank you @S O  for the help..

Comment: I've made an edit to this answer (It may not get accepted as it has to go through peer review) but I've added comments and event handlers to stop a potential infinite loop and did a bit of a general tidy up.

Comment: Thanks. I caught that bug after posting the answer. Change Event is being called again and again because i'm changing that cell in the function. i'll work with your changes and try if its working.

Comment: Edit seems to have been applied